# message to specific client using sockets

Tags: java

I have 2 classes

```
 public class ServerStart implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                serverSock = new ServerSocket(2101);
                while (true) 
                {
                    sock = serverSock.accept();
                    System.out.println(sock);
                    clients.put(sock.getPort(),sock);
                    HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
                    hmc.messagetospecificclients(String ipaddress,String choice)
                }
```

2nd class is

```
public class HandleMultipleClients
{

    Socket soc;
    ServerSocket serverSock;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    public HandleMultipleClients()
    {

    }
    public void messagetospecificclients(String ipaddress,String choice) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.print(ipaddress+"\n"+choice);
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        {
            System.out.print("ok1");
            int key = iter.next();
            java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);
            InetAddress zee = client.getInetAddress();
            String s = zee.getHostAddress();
            System.out.print(s);
            if (zee.getHostAddress().equals(ipaddress))
            {
                System.out.print("ok2");
                dos =new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(choice);
           }
```

How can i get through for loop of 2nd class function i.e messagetospecificclients(String ipaddress,String choice) when i am adding clients to the first class kindly help me. My code should be like that i should add the clients to first class and should traverse the for loop in 2nd class

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure the code. Separate the code for the mechanics for the socket server and the manipulation of the return data. The return data code can be launched from messageToSpecificClient method. You could launch a whole class or whatever just from that.
I have not run this, but it should run.
Another caveat about this code is that it will have issues with some unicode.
So if that is in your requirements that will need to be changed some.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MultiThreadServer implements Runnable
{
    Socket  csocket;

    MultiThreadServer(Socket csocket)
    {
        this.csocket = csocket;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Listening");
        while (true)
        {
            Socket sock = ssock.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            new Thread(new MultiThreadServer(sock)).start();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        PrintStream pstream = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        try
        {
            pstream = new PrintStream(csocket.getOutputStream());
            input = csocket.getInputStream();
            String stringFromClient = readFromInputStream(input);
            String response = messageTosSpecificClients(stringFromClient);
            pstream.write(response.getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pstream != null)
                try
                {
                    pstream.close();
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                }
            if (input != null)
                try
                {
                    input.close();
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                }
            if (csocket != null)
                try
                {
                    csocket.close();
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                }
        }
    }

    String readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        int ch;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((ch = inputStream.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) ch);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String messageTosSpecificClients(String choice) throws IOException
    {
        String ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";

        String retData = "General Return String";
        System.out.print(ipaddress + "\n" + choice);
        InetAddress zee = csocket.getInetAddress();
        String s = zee.getHostAddress();
        System.out.print(s);
        if (zee.getHostAddress().equals(ipaddress))
        {
            retData = "Specific Return String";
        }
        return retData;
    }
}
```